# Find out various layouts used in website

Tags: html-parsing

Is it possible to find out the total no of layouts (templates) used within a website.
For example:-
Suppose i want to know how many types of layouts www.flipkart.com uses.
Answer will be like:-

1. Landing page or Home page
2. Category Page e.g http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles?_l=GIuT6NCRsZbfL9ID9ZKHNQ--&_r=hCno5y6eFUI8C0iWzaQbAg--&ref=cef19a11-4ebc-4f8e-a0dc-401c2d55de3e&_pop=brdcrumb
   This is a category page. All such pages will have same layout only the inner content will be different.
3. Product Pages like http://www.flipkart.com/htc-sensation-mobile-phone/p/itmczbrsnwphgbnw?pid=MOBCYW9HXBUDYJPH&_l=sXQjsX87GxqrvKzhjuOrkw--&_r=n_2yuAC4xgh0SZTuulvAtw--&ref=9305103f-6fc1-497c-807a-8f30ee30c13c is a product page.
   All the product pages will have same layout like they have buy now option. Multiple images will be there. So Is there any existing tool to find out this.

I hope i am clear in my question. I just want to classify the site pages into some buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't think there exists some kind of tool or algorithm now upto my knowledge but yes you can write some. Try to find out some attributes of these pages and set them as benchmarks. Now whenever you encounter a url and you want to identify its category just find out the attributes again and compare against the benchmarks set.
Its not generic though but will work for specific websites :)